# Tag common-language-interface seems incorrect

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

What is [common-language-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-language-interface)? For me it seems that this is a mistake and it should be named *common-language-infrastructure*.

There are only 4 questions with this tag and all refer to something that has to do with [clr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clr) or [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net).

I can edit these question by myself, but first I would like to know if this is some new technology or if I´m correct that this is a mistake.

Comment: I agree the tag is badly/wrongly named, it sort of jumps at you in this link [Standard ECMA-335 Common Language Infrastructure](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm). For only 4 questions I wonder if we need that tag at all?

Answer (score 6):

I retagged those 4 questions. The [common-language-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-language-interface) is now clear of questions and <strike>will be</strike> is removed by the script that <strike>runs</strike> ran at 03:00 UTC

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion common-language-interface has to do with cli of .net technology and sould be used with cli,clr or.net

Comment: No, the tag is completly wrongly named as OP already pointed out. It shouldn't be used in any combination. (which is no longer possible because the tag is gone)